# When and where is "oui" read /wei/?

Tags: prononciation

Oui is usually [read](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oui):

> /wi/

On occasion I hear oui read:

> /wei/

with an extra sound in the middle.

Is this common? Where and when will you come across such pronunciation?

Comment: Where did you hear it and are you sure of what you heard? Are you sure it was /wei/ and not /wɛ/ (or /we/)? Is it really two syllables /we.i/ or is it a diphtong /wej/? Either way *[ouais](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ouais)* is a very common synonym of *oui* in colloquial French, but your description /wei/ just doesn't sound like something a French speaker would say.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' ouais is definitely the word. I'm hearing it in Switzerland, perhaps that would account for the variation?

Comment: Perhaps. It isn't something I remember hearing, but I don't frequent a lot of Swiss French.

Comment: It's also possible that I'm confusing the /ɛ/ with /ei/.

Comment: The most obvious source of a /ei/ diphthong in Swiss French is the long final vowel /eː/ (as in aimée, bouée, etc), which is know to undergo that sound change, but ouais typically has a short /ɛ/ rather a long /e/

Comment: Maybe in ze German areas ;)

Answer (score 19):

Approval is often expressed with ***ouais*** (pronounced /wɛ/, sometimes /we/) instead of ***oui*** (/wi/) in relaxed spoken French. The difference is similar to using **yep** vs **yes**.

A final /j/ might be heard in Switzerland as you noticed<sup>1</sup>.

This /**wɛj**/ variant is also present in Marseille, often with a prepended /v/ leading to ***voueï*** pronounced /**vwɛj**/.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Note that there is no single French Swiss pronunciation. There are several different accents depending on the *cantons* (Geneva, Vaud, Valais, Jura, Fribourg...) and variations, sometimes also significant, inside them.</sub>

Answer (score 17):

"Oui" is always pronounced /wi/

"Ouais" is vey common in French, it is slang for "Oui" like "Yeah" is slang for "Yes".

Answer (score 6):

The normal pronunciation of *oui* is /wi/: a single syllable consisting of a semivowel followed by a vowel.

There is a very common variant which is spelled *[ouais](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ouais)* and is pronounced /wɛ/. It's a colloquial word, which some speakers use a lot and others don't use much. Again, the semivowel /w/ is followed by a vowel /ɛ/: the word ends in a vowel sound. The vowel is nominally /ɛ/, an [open-mid front unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel), which is the “è sound”.

In some accents (mostly from the south of France), /ɛ/ doesn't exist and /e/ (a [close-mid unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_unrounded_vowel), the “é sound”) is used instead. Even in accents that do have separate /ɛ/ and /e/ sounds, some words always have /e/ (for example the “é” word ending), some words always have /ɛ/ (for example, in [closed syllables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable#closed_syllable), i.e. when there is a consonant after the vowel in the same syllable), and some words can fluctuate. A final /ɛ/ in a word is subject to fluctuation (as shown for example in [regional variations for *piquet* and *poulet*](https://francaisdenosregions.com/2017/07/06/ces-mots-qui-ne-se-prononcent-pas-de-la-meme-facon-dun-bout-a-lautre-de-la-france/)) and many speakers have a degree of free variation between them. So pronouncing *ouais* as /we/ is fairly common, even though dictionaries only list /wɛ/ (and it even happens with speakers who would tell you that they only ever pronounce /wɛ/).

Adding a trailing /j/ [semivowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semivowel) is not a common variation. It isn't something I ever remember hearing. But it may be a regional variation that I'm not familiar with. (I'm French, and while've lived in Paris for most of my life and I meet people from all regions of France, I'm not particularly familiar with patterns of speech that people might drop when they move to the capital, and I don't know many Swiss French speakers.) The etymology of *[ouais](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ouais)* is disputed, and it may have been influenced by other forms with a trailing /i/ or /j/ sound.

On the other hand, I'd be surprised by a two-syllable pronunciation /wei/, with the vowel /i/ at the end. It's really far from the mainstream pronunciation.

Are you sure of what you heard, though? I've noticed that to English native speakers, /ɛ/, /jɛ/ and /ɛj/ are barely distinguishable, whereas the same utterances sound completely different to a French speaker. English speakers commonly describe *ouais* as sounding like “way”, but to a French speaker it's more like “weh”: it's an open syllable.

There is a two-syllable pronunciation of *oui*, but it's /u:.i/, starting with a long /u/ and without an /ɛ/ or /e/ sound. It's uncommon and only used to mean “after some hesitation, I'm answering yes”, much in the same way that in English you can say “yyyyyes” starting with a long /i/.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers, you may hear */wei/* in a specific situation when someone is explicitly exaggerating and mispronouncing *oui* to make a point and show annoyment.

> - hi, it's me again!
> - */wei/*?...

I would say that this is a *oué* that is longer and usually in a higher pitch.

Answer (score 0):

« Ouais » (/we/) is a colloquial  (familier) term used to say « oui » ([TLFI](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ouais)). It can be used for a plain replacement nowadays. However, in the past this word was loaded with connotations and today it is still used that way (ironical, contemptuous, …).

In formal conversation you should avoid using this word; it is acceptable among friends or colleagues but considered by some people to be lax language if not vulgar.

Comment: No, “ouais” is not pronounced /wei/. There is no /i/ or even /j/ sound. And it's informal, but definitely not vulgar.

Comment: I can’t possibly supply a reference, but I’ve *definitely* heard, in French movies, both /wei/ and a variation where the final sound is de-voiced, resulting in something like / wiç/.

Comment: @DavidGarner The true pronunciation is  /wɛ/ but you find /we/ and then there are all sorts of possibilities from less than careful speakers, in particular /wɘ/.

Comment: @DavidGarner Nevertheless the English listener must be careful while his/her ear is not yet well trained in French, as the sound /e/ does not exist in English in final position and there is a tendency for him/her to decode it as /ei/ (this one is common in final position in English).

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' that might true if I’d grown up as a speaker of RP English, but I grew up in Yorkshire where ‘day’ (e.g.) is widely pronounced /de:/.